# Testing for where noise is produced

Tags: recording, noise

I've lately been trying to record my guitar/bass using logic pro X as a bit of a hobby but unfortunately I get ridiculous amounts of noise when I try to record. I am not sure where this noise is coming from and so it would be pretty helpful if anyone new of a way(s) to test for it's origin.

I record using a Nio 2|4 USB interface (My budget is not very big) using my guitar/bass with a fairly standard 3m cable into logic pro X's amp modelling kit.

Is it more likely to be one of these or is it a combination of them all?

I am willing to buy a new interface, install noiseless pickups, buy a new lead or mess with logic pro but I don't have the money to do all of them so some guidance would be great.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to a 7 various recordings:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4iwvg9w585hdsc/Noise%20Test.m4a

1. Guitar input on 0, Audio Interface Volume on 0
2. Guitar input on 10, Audio Interface Volume on 0
3. Guitar input on 0, Audio Interface Volume on 10
4. Guitar input on 10, Audio Interface Volume on 10
5. Blank mp3 through logic amp (Metronome added)
6. Control measure - SFX: dog barking without amp
7. Control measure - SFX: dog barking with amp

Comment: It would be important to know _what_ kind of noise this is you're experiencing. Easiest, you upload a sample.

Comment: Just added one now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like fairly standard white noise, amplified a lot through high-gain amp simulator setting (which BTW you might consider simply lowering, many digital simulation presets have the gain just absurdly high with little sound benefit). This has definitely nothing to do with your guitar (except that it's output level may be not exceptionally high), it's mainly a factor of the interface's guitar-in preamp (and possibly later circuit, i.e. AD-converter). Apparently, the input just isn't much good.

You're quite sure you use the right input (guitar impedance, not line) and don't have any other input mixed in, right?

Comment: Yeah, it's just my guitar going into the guitar input jack. I understand that the noise is being amplified by the amp simulator, but I'm more questioning why this noise exists rather than just adjusting my settings to hide it. Are you suggesting that the issue is probably with the quality of the pre-amp's electronics?

Comment: The will always _exist_ some noise, it's a physical necessity (though, if you cool your preamp with liquid helium-3...). Of course, good preamps will have little noise, and poor ones sometimes have inacceptibly much, so I'd wager that's indeed the problem in your case. Novation makes great synths, but that expertise probably didn't help or was even counterproductive (in synths, everything is low-impedance while guitar input are very high-impedance, requiring rather different design considerations).